# Why does my .sh script with pipenv runs correctly manually but not throug a cron?

Tags: debian, cron, root

I've been having issues lately with a cron script that has been running for a long time and suddenly stopped working. The script runs on root crontab.
The organization is as follows:

- In the crontab i execute a `run_script.sh` script
- Inside the .sh script i execute cd to a specific directory and then execute `pipenv run python script.py`

The `run_script.sh` works correctly if manually executed, but when is triggered by cron it returns an error of importing a library which is present in python3 (the script.py is written in python3) but not in python2. So i assume that for some reason there's gotta be a problem when setting up the venv using pipenv even though the logs only show an import library error.

I've tried changing the `run_script.sh` to `pipenv run python3 script.py` and still got the same error log.

Also tried setting the PATH env in both the cron file and the `run_script.sh` adding the path to python3 to the existing PATH and that didn't work for me neither.

Lastly i `sudo apt update && upgrade` the machine and still the script doesn't work.

Here are the outputs of `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu 5.7.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.10-1 (2020-07-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux


No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because thru a cron, the initialization of the process is different, all of your .profiles and things like that will not be run. So the environment is different.

Comment: what's weird is that the script used to run correctly until a few days ago, and i've changed nothing sice it has stopped running. I'm really lost here

Answer (score -2):

Jobs run through `cron`, or `systemd` startup scripts aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop. `systemd` startup scripts are run as `root`. None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`).

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.

Since the `command` part of the `crontab` line is, by default,  interpreted by `/bin/sh`, which has a simpler syntax than `/bin/bash`, I recommend having `command` be a call to a `bash` script  (executable, mounted, starts with `#!/bin/bash`) which sets up the environment,  then calls the desired program.